# when doing query for parseUsers and shoing them in listFragment, while switching fast from fragment to fragment the app crashs

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-listfragment

Sorry for asking near same questions, cause my low reputation can't comment there.

So I am using parse.com and doing a query for users and putting them in a list that in fragment.

The app works, but when I switching between fragments fast, it crashes with exception:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

before my code was in onResume, but as I understand need to be in onCreateView, still don't understand why, cause onResume comes after onCreateView. Anyway this is mu code:

```
public class FriendsFragment extends ListFragment {

protected List<ParseUser> mFriends;
protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;

@InjectView(R.id.fragmentFriendsSpinner) ProgressBar mSpinner;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
    query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_LASTNAME);
    query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_FIRSTNAME);
    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
            mSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (e == null) {
                // Success
                mFriends = friends;
                int usersAmount = mFriends.size();
                String[] fullNames = new String[usersAmount];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                    fullNames[i] = user.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FIRSTNAME) + " " +
                            user.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_LASTNAME);
                    i++;
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getListView().getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        fullNames
                );
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                mSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                // Show error to user
                OkCustomDialog dialog = new OkCustomDialog(
                        getListView().getContext(),
                        getString(R.string.friend_list_updating_error_title),
                        e.getMessage());
                dialog.show();

            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

and this catLog I received:

```
06-11 08:18:47.526  25134-25134/com.example.android.donotbelateapp     W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x41c54c08)
06-11 08:18:47.531  25134-25134/com.example.android.donotbelateapp  E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.donotbelateapp, PID: 25134
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
        at com.example.android.donotbelateapp.ui.fragments.FriendsFragment$1.done(FriendsFragment.java:71)
        at com.example.android.donotbelateapp.ui.fragments.FriendsFragment$1.done(FriendsFragment.java:56)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line 71 is 
     ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is because public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) is executed when response of background task is received BUT your fragment is not present there as its destroyed. So the app crashes.

Comment: fix me if I wrong. The "public void done" is processing after app received the query. So why would be the situation as you described? And if it so, what I need to do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I understood you answer Qamar. Please post it as the answer that I could vote for you. And would be glad for solution =).

Comment: One of the solutions that I thought is canceling movement from fragment to fragment (how to do it? ) till list would be created. And other is canceling touch of the screen (again how to do it? ).

Comment: What I eventually did is putting the code in parent Activity. I hope it is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because public void done(List friends, ParseException e) is executed when response of background task is received BUT your fragment is not present there as its destroyed. So the app crashes.

I think you should put the loaded data in storage(DB), OR ApplicationData(Not Recomended). so In your fragment check if data is already available then do not load it.